# What is the definition of the value supplied by the Android function View.getHitRect()?

Tags: android

"Hit rectangle in parent's coordinates". But what does that mean?

To amplify, what I really want to know is the meaning of the phrase "hit rectangle". What is it for? How does the framework process it? When in the lifecycle is the return value meaningful? How might it differ from the rectangle defined by `getLeft()`,`getTop()`, `getRight()`, `getBottom()`?

Based on the name of the function I can of course guess at an answer, and try a few examples, but that's not satisfactory. I can find nothing useful about this function on the Android Developer website, or anywhere else I've looked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html#delegate) appears to be the most complete explanation.

> The getHitRect() method gets the child's hit rectangle (touchable
>   area) in the parent's coordinates.

The example snippet uses the function to determine the current touchable area of a child view (after layout) in order to effectively extend it by creating a `TouchDelegate`

Answer (score 1):

They should certainly do a better job of documenting. If you look at the source `View#getHitRect(Rect)`, you'll see that if the view has an "identity matrix", or is not attached to a window, it returns exactly what we're thinking. The alternate branch means the view has a transform, therefore to get the 'hit rect' for the parent, which is the smallest possible rect in its coordinate system that covers view, you have to move the rect to origin, run the transform and then add back its original position.

So you can use it as a shortcut for this purpose if there's no transform. If there's a transform, remember that you'll be getting values in the rect that may be outside or inside the view as currently displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The `Rect` that is returned contains 4 values:

- bottom
- left
- right
- top

`bottom` specifies the y coordinate of the bottom of the rectangle.  `left` specifies the x coordinate of the left side of the rectangle. etc.

The parent coordinate means that the hit rectangle values are specified in the parent's coordinate system.

Imagine yourself standing in an open field at night, looking up at the moon.  Your position on the earth can be expressed in many ways.

If we expressed your position in your local coordinate system, you would be located at (latitude/longitude) (0, 0).  As you walk around, your local coordinate system never changes, you are always centered at (0,0) in your local coordinate system.

However, if we expressed your location using the earth's coordinate system, you might be at (latitude, longitude) (16, 135).

You are standing on earth, so earth is your parent coordinate system.

In the same way, a View may be contained in a LinearLayout.  The LinearLayout would be the View's parent and so the values from getHitRect() would be expressed in the coordinate system of the LinearLayout.

**EDIT**

In generic terms *hit rectangle* is a term used to define a rectangular area used for collision detection.  In terms of Android, a hit rectangle is just an instance of type Rect.

The methods `getLeft()` etc are just accessors for the data in the Rect, so the members of a Rect define the same rectangle that you would get by calling the methods.

A common usage scenario for a Rect would be handling tap events:

```
//Imagine you have some Rect named myRect
//And some tap event named event
//Check if the tap event was inside the rectangle
if(myRect.contains(event.getX(), event.getY()){
  //it's a hit!
}
```

You might also want to see if two rectangle's intersect each other

```
if(myRect.contains(myRect2)){
   //collision!
}
```

For a View, the hit rectangle isn't really used directly, you can [see the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java/).  Top, bottom, left, right are used a ton in the View but the getHitRect() method is really more of a convenience to pass back those parameters (top/bottom/left/right) to people that need them in a tidy package.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I'm afraid it begs the question somewhat. The code you point to indicates that getHitRect() sometimes returns the rectangle defined by getLeft(), getTop() etc. but not always. So what's the difference? What I specifically ask is exactly what rectangle the function returns, in meaningful semantic terms. You'll appreciate that the function is of little value without a precise answer. I conclude that as the documentation of the function specifies no behaviour then none is guaranteed, so it's effectively unusable. I'll be avoiding it.