# How to determine when a Android view percentage visible area has changed?

Tags: android, performance, view

I am trying to get some kind of listener in Android view that tells me precisely when a view's visible are has changed for user. More specifically, when the view has moved or something has blocked some pixels of the view visible area, i want to get notified so that I can calculate its new visible percentage.

I have tried attaching ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener but that is getting triggered so many times and if calculate new visible area percentage on every ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener call then it degrades my app performance.
Is there any more precise way to get notified when a View's visible area percentage has changed?

Comment: So have you seen/tried: [What is the definition of the value supplied by the Android function View.getHitRect()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13296162/295004) or [detect if views are overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26252710/295004)?

Comment: I know how to find visible percentage area, I just want some sort of listener to trigger that percentage calculation. ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener for e.g. gets called multiple times which triggers this calculation of visible area percentage multiple times too causing perf issues.

Comment: You might want to explain what is blocking the visible area as ['overdraw' is a known performance penalty](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/overdraw), or try to explain the goal of calculating visible percentage.

Comment: So these views are just some images, and I want to know what area of those images or tiles were visible to the user and I also want to keep reporting if that visible area percentage changes. So for e.g. if image is half visible to user, I want to report 50%, and if lets say user scrolls or does something on the UI causing the same image to become 75% visible, I want to report that too. So basically I want to get some kind of a listener whenever this percentage visible area of the image view changes.